# The name 'MyCall' is not recognized in the current context (3CX, CallFlowDesigner, ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, 3cx, call-flow

I'm trying to integrate the script of a callflow made with call flow designer (3CX), with the aim of using an ASP.NET web application to trigger the callflow via an external URL. However, I'm encountering a problem with MyCall. In the 3CX documentation, it's indicated 'Basic work with the MyCall object provided by CallFlowScriptingCore'. So, I integrate CallFlowScriptingCore.dll into the assemblies, but it does not seem to be recognized. Has anyone had the same error (MyCall) when integrating this script into an external app? I must be missing something. Your help is more than welcome.Thanks in advance to the community.
[Capture img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3aaC.png)